# Why I cannot rename filename of react component?

Tags: reactjs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to rename component filename to capital letter, but it doesn't allow me. In WSL terminal it says:

I try: `mv mamaMia.jsx MamaMia.jsx`

responds: `mv: 'mamaMia.jsx' and 'MamaMia.jsx' are the same file`

that file is in `src/components/` of my application

Why is that?
How can I rename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WSL, Windows volumes are mounted as case insensitive by default. You can either manually mount the volumes as case sensitive by following this [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/improved-per-directory-case-sensitivity-support-in-wsl) for example, or trick the shell by using a temporary name as an extra step of your rename:

```
mv mamaMia.jsx MamaMia-temp.jsx
mv MamaMia-temp.jsx MamaMia.jsx
```

Comment: you're right. And yet, if I start typing `Mam` and press TAB to autocomplete it doesn't work. Gotta be careful

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is so annoying I've tried the commands provided by the article but it seems that it only work when your project is set on the c/ directory and not the root folder. The problem with that is that trying to start a React app on the c/ folder doesn't work (hot reload doesnt work). Your solution seems to be the only one working so far...